# What is the maximum number of SMTP threads I can use for sending email with mailgun

Tags: mailgun

I want to send many emails using Atom Park email software using mailgun

I want to know what is the maximum amount of threads I can set in the SMTP server settings for mailgun

Comment: have you read the [doc](https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/faqs.html)

Comment: Yes, however I can not see any information about maximum threads for SMTP